# How can I alias sql select columns in laravel query builder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a query like this where I am not sure how to alias the select columns for each table. Could you help me with that?

```
$columns = array_merge(json_decode($data->columns), json_decode($data->columns2));

$result = DB::table($data->type)
                    ->select($columns)
                    ->join('tabs', 'data.id', '=', 'tabs.id')
                    ->get();
```

Comment: what is the value of ```$columns```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you add `AS newColumnName` as you would in SQL:

`->select(['name AS title', 'email AS emailAddress'])`.

Additionally, you really really don't want to pass table names and column names unsanitized to your query like this. They are NOT sanitized by Laravel and are a potential vulnerability. More info can be found in the callout box at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses

From the comments I concluded you want to select the columns from `$data->columns` and alias them like they're in `$data->columns2`. I don't know the data structure for neither, but I think you mean something like this:

```
$select = array_map(
    function($column, $alias) {
        return "{$column} AS {$alias}";
    }, 
    $data->columns,
    $data->columns2
);

var_dump($select);
```

Here's a sandbox: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/12487b8f2d590aa9f0d7a6cb0d7d4f1f067b4cb0

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question :(

Comment: Did I misunderstand the question? You were asking how to alias when selecting columns right?

Comment: But for the specific case scenario where the columns are passed as variable

Comment: I'm telling you that you really shouldn't :) But if you really want to... I'll update my answer.